# dhcpd pool exhaustion - What's the result?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, dhcp-server

I have a DHCP server that serves leases to several houndred, maybe up to a thousand, different clients on an average day. The pool consists of 242 IPs, and due to the highly dynamic nature of the network, it's enough 99% of the time (most devices are gone from the network in a few minutes), despite having a lease time of 3600.

Now, imagine if more clients than that connect to the network during an hour. The sollution is obvious: Decrease lease time, or increase the DHCP pool, however, what i would like to know: What happens when dhcpd has exhausted the pool? Are new DHCP requests simply ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system will simply stop assigning IP addresses once the leases have been exhausted. This will also be reflected in the DHCP server's `/var/log/messages`. E.g. "No free leases".

```
DHCPDISCOVER from 00:40:ee:40:38:f8 via eth0: network 10.1.1.0/24: no free leases
```

On the device side, they will either get 0.0.0.0 or self-assigned 169.x.x.x addresses...

Is expanding your subnet an option?

Comment: plenty of options, that being one of them. It's not a realy problem, i would just prefer to know what the result would if no action was taken.

Answer (score 2):

If your DHCP pool has been exhausted then your server will stop giving out addresses - it will not use up the oldest unused lease.

Comment: is this part of the standard behavior of DHCP? Is there any way to set DHCP to lease unused/freed leases?